# Nagios will not run external commands such as mutt and ec2 commands

Tags: amazon-ec2, nagios, mutt

I have Nagios up and running on an Amazon EC2 instance as their custom Linux and it is monitoring several processes (both on local and remote hosts) quite well. It is running my customs scripts without any issue.

That being said it will not run mutt nor will it run the ec2 command line tools (ex. ec2-describe-instances) even though when I try to run these commands and my scripts as the Nagios user they work fine.

The only help that I have found through Google is that in the nagios.cfg I need to set:
   check_external_commands=1
and
   check_command_interval=-1 (-1 makes it check as often as possible)

Both of these variables are set as such in my nagios.cfg and yet the externals still don't seem to be executing. I have attempted to redirect their output to a file and all that is being printed there are blank lines. All suggestions are appreciated and again thank you in advance.

Update: Tried adding these commands to /root, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Technically what you're describing isn't what Nagios refers to as an external command.  An external command is ran completely outside of Nagios, and puts its 'output' into the external command file (command_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd).  IOWs, these are commands that are 'not' ran by Nagios.

For Nagios to run the command it must be in the command file.  Is the full path to these non-external commands correctly entered in your commands.cfg file?  What does it say in the nagios log and debug files?